# Angularjs (How to make responsive website)

Tags: angularjs

I want to start learning angularjs responsive web development.

Kindly suggest me what option should I folow one of below.

1. angularjs + angular plugins
2. angularjs + bootstrap (twitter)
3. angularjs + ?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to make AngularJs website responsive, you can use bootstrap, angular material, lumx etc..

Comment: As @Ali786 said there are plenty of options and most of them achieve most of the functionalities required for a website. but which one to choose depends on your requirement of how the look and feel of your website should be. Personally i prefer **angularjs** with **angular material**

Comment: This question is opinionated and would be flagged by a concerned member of stackoverflow soon, but i'll answer your question though. I've used angular material and bootstrap with angularjs and i've found bootstrap to be better. There's also UI bootstrap.